Mediawiki: I want to display all the possible values of a property
I have a property "Type d'évenement" that has 33190 uses. I want to display all the different values possible for that property.
Here's how it works now :
Attribut:Type d'événement
Here's the code :
Toutes les valeurs existantes :
{{#arraydefine: my.array
 | {{#ask: [[Type d'événement::+]] |mainlabel=- |headers=hide |?Type d'événement |limit=10000|searchlabel= }}
 |, | print=list, sort=asc, unique
}}

[[Has type::text| ]]

("Toutes les valeurs existantes" means "All possible values")
But this solution is very slow and is limited to the first 10000 usages, so I may miss some possible values.
What annoys me is that in the advanced research form it is perfect and work very fast (look at the "Type d'événement" combobox input):
Recherche avancée
It means that there is a way to do it perfectly and in a fast way. PageForms extension managed it.
I also tried this solution, that has the same problems :
{{#ask: [[Type d'événement::+]] |headers=hide |?Type d'événement |limit=10000|format=valuerank }}

This solution I found on the mediawiki documentation :
Help:List_the_set_of_unique_values_for_a_property
There is also this page that do it really fast :Search by property
I have not yet installed any lua extension to do codes in templates but I may try it one day. I can also do some php and js code in the server files if necessary.

There is no good solution to this problem.
Either you close the list of possible events ("allows value" or "allows value list" special property) then you can query this property to retrieve the list, or you make a bit more sophisticated code to count (using "count" result format) and get all possible values with multiple queries (batches of 10000) using the "offset" query parameter and a few variables.
The first solution is recommended, it offers less freedom for the user but garanties integrity and consistency of data. Moreover updating allowed values is fast and easy.

I have found myself a solution. I made my own extension to make a magic word that does the job. It is heavily inspired by how the page form extension gets the possible values for a combobox for example

Very bad idea...

Care to explain why ?
